# How to redirect form php page to different Angularjs template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I have create login page in php.**(example url:  test.com/login)**

and signup page.**(example url:  test.com/signup)**

when user login then page redirect in an Angular application.**(example url:  test.com/admin#/)**

**But**

**Case 1:**

when user login then redirect into **example url:  test.com/admin/#Dashboard**

**Case 2:**

when user login by after signup then redirect into **example url:  test.com/admin/#accountverify**

**How can I do above cases?**

Angular route Code:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when("/", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/accountverify.html", controller: "cpController"})
            .when("/Dashboard", {templateUrl: "angular/templates/dashboard.html", controller: "AdminDashController"})
            .when("/accountverify", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/accountverify.html", controller: "cpController"})
            .when("/agreement", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/agreement.html", controller: "cpController"})
            .when("/termnservices", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/termnservices.html", controller: "cpController"})
            .when("/mobileverify", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/mobileverify.html", controller: "cpController"})
            .otherwise("/accountverify", {templateUrl: "angular/cpModule/templates/accountverify.html", controller: "cpController"});
}]);
```

I appreciate all response.

Comment: After sign up is success then redirect to /accountverify.

Comment: yes  @Sharan De Silva

Comment: how can i do this by using ngRoute rather than using ui-route?

Answer (score 1):

Use state param,

```
angular.module('myApp', [ … ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/login/:param1', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Pass some value in param1 based on that value you can redirect your view

In controller,

```
if($stateParams.param1 == 'AFTER_SIGNUP'){
    /* accountverify page */
}else{
    /* login page */
}
```

Comment: I think this way can not be used here. Because here we redirect from php page to angular application. So where define 'stateParams' ?